# How to compile a typescript project for server side with webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

I set up webpack to compile a project with typescript.
However, the project is a server-side node project that must be used as a linked library from another server-side project.
If I compile it with webpack I'll get a window reference error.
On the other side, if I compile just with tsc it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong here or it is just like this?
Or maybe there is something I don't understand about linking libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at webpack target configurations:

Try to configure:
`target: "node"`

The default is
`target: "web"`,

That's why you are experiencing issues regarding `window` object.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#target